# scikit-learn: compute & plot recursive KBEST features (k='all') performance

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, bigdata

My goal:

- With [`SelectKBest` (`KBest`)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest) and `k="all"`, sort ranked features (easy & done)
- Plot the recursive/progressive **cross-validated** performance of the sorted features ([pretty much as this example for recursive feature elimination, RFECV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py)), that is, 1) compute the cross-validated performance of the top-most feature, 2) then compute the cv performance of the top-most + second top-most, 3) then + third, ... n) all features combined. (bit painstaking & not done)
- Plot the results as in the figure below (just, instead of the RFECV, with the sorted `KBest-all` features). (easy).

Yes, I could `k`-loop over all the ranked features, then "transform" the data to only allow the `k` best features, then calculate the cross validation performance for each, then finally get all scores and plot... -- I want to avoid this code.

I'm looking forward for an **standard answer** for *I guess* some wrapper function like this must already exist in the excellent `scikit-learn` library.

Perhaps doable with [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) ?

[image]

Comment: probably this is the function (RFECV, instead of RFE) that you should be looking for.  Feature ranking with recursive feature elimination and cross-validated selection of the best number of features. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html

Comment: Yes -- My bad, I meant to write RFECV originally

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a standard solution, so this is pseudocode of what I did:

*(happy to provide a Jupyter working example if there is interest)*

```
def get_sorted_kbest_feature_keys(kbest_fitted_model):
    return [fkey for fkey, _ in sorted(enumerate(kbest_fitted_model.scores_), key=lambda tuple: tuple[1], reverse=True)]

def select_features_transformer_function(X, **kwargs):
    selected_feature_keys = kwargs["selected_feature_keys"]

    X_new = X[:, selected_feature_keys]
    # apply other transformers as desired

    return X_new
```

-

```
kbest = SelectKBest(scoring_func, k="all")  # scoring_func like "f1_macro"
kbest.fit(X, y)
selected_feature_keys = get_kbest_sorted_feature_keys(kbest)

scores = []

for num_seletected_kbest_features in range(1, num_features + 1):

    selected_feature_keys = sorted_kbest_feature_keys[:num_seletected_kbest_features]
    my_transformer = FunctionTransformer(select_features_transformer_function, accept_sparse=True, kw_args={"selected_feature_keys": selected_feature_keys})

    classifier = # example SVC
    estimator = make_pipeline(my_transformer, classifier)

    cv_scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, scoring=scoring_name, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1)
    scores.append(cv_scores.mean())

# Then I can plot the scores as in:

### http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py
```